# Python Crontab Overwrites the previous job instead of creating a new one

Tags: python, centos, cron, cron-task

Pasting my python code below:

```
from crontab import CronTab

tab = CronTab()
cmd1 = 'actual command'

cron_job = tab.new(cmd)
cron_job.minute.every(1)

cron_job.enable()
tab.write_to_user(user=True)
```

I am setting these cronjob based on some user input on an app. So overtime a user clicks submit, I want to create a new cronjob under the same crontab file (since its a webapp, it runs under the context of a standard user).

But it seems every time a user clicks submit, my crontab overwrites the previous task. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are recreating the `tab` variable on each request does not append to the crontab in question; it overwrites it.

If you pass `user=True` to the `CronTab` constructor you will be able to append to the existing crontab:

```
from crontab import CronTab

tab = CronTab(user=True)
cmd1 = 'echo Hello'
cmd2 = 'echo CronTab'

job1 = tab.new(cmd1)
job1.minute.every(1)
job1.enable()

job2 = tab.new(cmd2)
job2.hour.every(1)
job2.enable()

print list(tab.commands)  # ['echo Hello', 'echo CronTab']

# Explicitly specify we want the user's crontab:
tab2 = CronTab(user=True)

print list(tab2.commands)  # ['echo Hello', 'echo CronTab']
```